# rsync comparing directories of large binary files: is it comparing the content of the files?

Tags: rsync

I have two hard disks with movie files on them and I need them to have the same contents.

I'm using `rsync` to make sure that disk B has the same files on it as disk A, and it seems to be transferring everything.

I have added around 10 new movies to disk A and all I wanted was for `rsync` to quickly note which ones were new and copy them.

What I'm doing is

`rsync -rv -P /Volumes/DISK_A/Film/ /Volumes/DISK_B/Film/`

(both locally mounted USB disks) and I assumed it would skip 99% of the files and only transfer across the new additions.

But it seems to be transferring everything:

```
Alien/Alien (1979).avi
   735027200 100%   17.24MB/s    0:00:40 (xfer#2, to-check=329/333)
Alien/Aliens (1986).avi
   945698816 100%   16.27MB/s    0:00:55 (xfer#3, to-check=328/333)
Animated/Aladdin (1992).avi
   869096258 100%   16.67MB/s    0:00:49 (xfer#5, to-check=325/333)
```

and those movies were already there both on source and destination.

The files are the same, the details look exactly the same if I do `ls -la`, same permissions, owner, size etc.

Is rsync having to do some kind of deep check of the *bytes* in the file in order to see whether it's truly the same? Because it's pretty slow and I don't need it to do that.

What I really want is an `rsync` command which means 'copy files on source which don't exist on destination and ignore every other factor.'

TIA.

Comment: Could run the `rsync` with the `--itemize` and `--dry-run` flag and post the first lines? Are both filesystems the same? Also, a ' ls -l' for some of the files that would be transferred (on both systems) might help explain your issue.

Comment: `ls -l` on source and destination for one or two files that are being repeatedly copied please. What filesystem is source and destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the flag you're looking for is `--ignore-existing`

Comment: That flag should almost never be needed, and particularly it's not needed here. Think about the scenario where a file is only partly copied. This flag with tell `rsync` not to revisit it to fix the copy

Comment: i'm answering the question as asked, "an `rsync` command that copies files on source which don't exist on destination _and ignores every other factor_"

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this as the answer, it really was what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing either the `--archive` (`-a`) or `--times` (`-t`) flags. Without one of those `rsync` won't track the change time and so it cannot bypass files that look like they're already been copied

```
rsync -avP  /Volumes/DISK_A/Film/ /Volumes/DISK_B/Film/
```

or

```
 rsync -rtvP /Volumes/DISK_A/Film/ /Volumes/DISK_B/Film/
```

Note that because you're copying locally, the clever part of `rsync` is disabled: you will either get a full copy or it's already copied. Unlike a network copy there's no ability to transfer only the missing/changed parts

Comment: Hi, thanks, even with those flags it still didn't work but that's probably because of different filesystems, see comments below the original post.

Comment: @AmbroseChapel tell us the filesystems and you'll get a correct answer. For example if FAT is involved there is a necessary workaround to cope with its 2 second timestamp granularity. Also be aware that the first full copy with `-a` will be fixing up the timestamps; thereafter it will skip the files.